# How can I only allow access to webpage at certain times of day?

Tags: php

I am creating a website in which people order takeaways online. How can I only allow access to webpage at certain times of day? e.g. 5pm - 12pm etc...

**Update:**

I have figured out a solution which works with number of answers:

```
<?php
    if (date('G')>17) {
        header('Location: /closed.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Here's the basic idea I see: "if now is not between time X and time Y, don't continue serving this page"

Comment: I have tried to think of ways, but I couldn't. I will try to think of a method which works like your method ... I will update ASAP ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you just build this check into the page itself.  That way if it is outside the time you can return a page telling the users to come back between these certain hours.  Here is one way to do this:

```
if(date('G') > 17 and date('G') < 24)
    //return the real page -- look into 'header' for redirecting
else
    //return a come back later message
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying this code:

```
$time = localtime();
if($time['tm_hour']<17)
{
    echo 'Our business is currently closed, come back later!';
    exit;
}
```

If the local time is not between 17:00 and 00:00, the script will display a message and exit.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way of doing this is making use of a .htaccess file that redirects every single page/folder from the root down to index.php of the root folder. So that you can put a simple date() in the index.php and check if the current date is higher/lower than your restrictions.

But besides this, why are you willing to do this? It seems very SEO unfriendly and also, user unfriendly.

Also, make sure the Timezones are readed correctly, I'm in +1, but somebody else coulb be in -6. This is a really big difference!

Comment: Your time zone is irrelevant. The business stops delivering at 5PM their time, not your time.

Comment: Doesn't mean you have to downvote it though. I can't smell the business stops at that particular time, can I? I could not know if it had to be user-based or not.

Comment: I imagine people do not often order food to be delivered from a different time zone. However, there is merit in mentioning time zones, since the web host may not be in the same time zone as the physical business. There's no need to account for varying time zones per user, but there may be a need to account for that location difference.

Comment: True that, timezones are really tricky sometimes. Verificate it over and over again to make sure it works correctly. I hate dates in php, always a struggle to make it work flawless.

Comment: @Wiseguy now I will tag you, because now I am talking to your personally. In the other case, I was speaking in general, there was no need to tag you since it was not a personal reply.

Comment: @Wiseguy whoops, I forgot it there. That's for sure. Thanks for noticing. (but can not edit it anymore)